# Hard drive for alpine linux on QEMU

Tags: hard-drive, qemu

I want to run Alpine Linux on QEMU with a host OS of Windows so I downloaded the latest ISO image (named `alpine-standard.iso`). Then I set up a hard drive file with `qemu-img create -f qcow2 alpine-disk.qcow2 2048`. Then I used https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images#Creating_an_image where my command is:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -smp 8 -display sdl -hda alpine-disk.qcow2 -cdrom alpine-standard.iso -boot d
```

I boot in, log in to `root` and run `touch TEST`. Then I close QEMU hoping that the changes should be saved to `alpine-disk.qcow2` however its modification time has not changed. If I run the above command again there is no `TEST` file. What am I supposed to do to save changes to the disk file? Am I understanding QEMU's representation of hard drives wrong?

Side note: I cannot get `virt-manager` working, nor do I want to switch to other virtualization software.

Comment: Did you run the setup for alpine? You may just be making a file in RAM which obviously disappears after reboots.

Comment: I have found out that I need to run setup-alpine to link the virtual disk file, but that often freezes the virtual machine and I have to restart it and wipe the disk.